# Windows form stopwatch elapsed time

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, visual-studio-2017

My windows form application's task is call the method and checkBox1_CheckedChanged event when the time equals 10 seconds. But the program can't go to the if statement for something.

Timer:

```
private void timerAU_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        stopwatch.Start();
        time = stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss\.f");
        TimerAutoUpdateHelper();

        if (time.Equals("00:00:10.1"))
        {
            stopwatch.Reset();
            timerAU.Stop();

            thread.Join();
            thread.Abort();
            MessageBox.Show("OK!");
            checkBox1_CheckedChanged(sender, e);               
        }
    }
```

Checkbox:

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (checkBox1.Checked == true)
            {
                
                timerAU.Start();
                stopwatch.Start();
                

                thread = new Thread(() => DataProcess.DataFromPLC(new Form1()));
                thread.Start();

                Log.WriteLogFile(EventCategory.AUTOUPDATECHECKED);
            }
            else
            {
                stopwatch.Stop();
                MessageBox.Show(time);
                checkBox1.Checked = false;
                timerAU.Stop();

                thread.Join();
                thread.Abort();

                Log.WriteLogFile(EventCategory.AUTOUPDATEUNCHECKED);
            }
        }
```

Comment: `thread.Abort();` oh mamma mia, mamma mia .... _do not use that, ever_. To help you fix your issue, more context is needed. What kind of timer is that? What does TimerAutoUpdateHelper do? ...

Comment: Is the stopwatch a timer control as well?

Comment: TimerAutoUpdateHelper method contain this call method that query datas form PLC.

Comment: Which If statement can't go through? Inside the `timerAU_Tick` or `checkBox1_CheckedChanged`?

Comment: So, what are you trying to achieve here? In your words. Is it something along the lines of "On activation of the checkbox, Data from PLC shall be processed and displayed in UI for as long as 10 seconds. Then the checkbox shall automatically be reset." ?

Comment: Tyro what do you mean?

Comment: @Tyro I am pretty confident it is a [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: @tontonsevilla if statement (time.Equals("00:00:10.1")) never execute.

Comment: @G.Soós _"if statement (time.Equals("00:00:10.1")) never execute"_ why do you think, it should? You take a snapshot right after starting the watch. So it's either "00:00:00.0" or something not much more than that. And it is not going to change automagically until the if condition is checked.

Comment: @Fildor the point would be that when it is checked, the query that we want to restart at certain intervals will be executed, if the checkbox is unchecked it will stop the method.

Comment: Well, the thing is: The way you are doing it, it will _never_ be the value that you expect. The other thing is: The condition would only be true if it's the exact value. Not 10.2 not 15.7 , exactly 10.1. So you'd probably want something like `if( stopwatch.Elapsed > TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10) )`

Comment: In other words: What that code of yours is doing is: You start a stopwatch (imagine it to be a literal real world stopwatch for a moment). Right after that, to take a picture of it on your iPhone. Then you do something else. Then you compare that picture you took before to a picture of a stopwatch that shows 10.1 secs. I hope this shows why that code cannot possibly work as you expect.

Comment: Maybe the interval of the time ticks is per second and therefore the millisecond part will always be 0 and checking the equality with a .1 millisecond part to the string equivalent will never come true

Comment: Another note: [`Thread.Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.join?view=netcore-3.1) _"Blocks the calling thread until the thread represented by this instance terminates."_ So, it doesn't make sense to call `Thread.Abort` _after_ that (Thread.Abort is a "no no" anyways).

Comment: @Fildor thanks. I changed if condition and that solved my problem.

Comment: Nevertheless @Fildor 's suggestion is better than catching with a specific millisecond part

Comment: @G.Soós, I am glad to hear that your problem has been solved, you can click '✔' to mark your reply as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Solved my problem. I changed if statement and run successful! :)

```
if (stopwatch.Elapsed > TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10))
            {
                stopwatch.Reset();
                timerAU.Stop();

                thread.Join();
                
                MessageBox.Show("OK!");
                checkBox1_CheckedChanged(sender, e);               
            }
```

Comment: Are you sure? You're still using a thread, still using a Stopwatch to measure time, still blocking while waiting for the thread to finish. And that thread is building a new form, which will almost guarantee an exception. If you wanted to update the UI without blocking you could simply use the `Process<>` class. If you wanted to run a long running operation in the background you could use `await Thread.Run()` - this alone would eliminate the need for the timer and stopwatch.

Comment: Panagiotis Kanavos is referring to the [Progress<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.progress-1) class (and `Task.Run()`). Btw, the code you have here and in the question is nonsensical in WinForms.